# How to Keep New Scale Size Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scale

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a sprite that is constantly scaling *down* over the period of 60 seconds.  This sprite then scales *up* by 1.5 when collision occurs.

```
        -(void) update: (ccTime) deltaTime 

        {if(CGRectIntersectsRect([randomSprite boundingBox], [other boundingBox]))  {

        [SAE playEffect:@"collisionSoundEffect.mp3"];
        [randomSprite runAction:[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:3 scaleX:1.5 scaleY:1.5]];
```

The problem is when after 3 seconds it '*Pops*' back down to the size it would have been as if the collision didn't happen.

Which of course is smaller.

What I want the sprite to do is to **stay** the newSize after the collision.  Then for the sprite to keep scaling down as it was.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
[thisSpriteIsConstatnlyScalingDown runAction:[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:60 scaleX:.01 scaleY:.01]];
```

I'm trying to keep the new scaled size and start scaling down from that again.

Comment: Is that your entire update method ?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. At the end of your animation the sprite must have the scale given as argument (I tested it and it works). If you execute many animation at the same time, you should use the CCScaleTo instead. So what is your exactly problem?

Comment: @giorashc No, that is not my entire update method.

Comment: @Yannick Yes, the end of the animation the sprite is at the correct scale.  That works fine.  When the 3 seconds is up the scaled sprite automatically goes back down from the scaled up size and does so without any animation.  That's the problem.  I want the sprite to start scaling back down from the new size.  Remember that the sprite is constantly being scaled down over the period of 60 seconds - from full size to .01.  I've edited the post to show the scaling down code.  Thanks for your help, sorry it's unclear.

Comment: Use the ```CCScaleTo``` instead of the ```CCScaleBy``` action.

Comment: Can you please post your entire update method ? (or at least the relevant manipulated sprite code parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you have two actions running at the same time. After scale up action finishes, scale down action is still running.

```
#define kScaleDownActionTag 1
#define kScaleUpActionTag 2


    ...

    // start downscale action
    CCAction *action = /* your scale down action */;
    action.tag = kScaleDownActionTag;
    [sprite runAction:action];


    ...

    if(CGRectIntersectsRect([randomSprite boundingBox], [other boundingBox]))  
    {
        // if scale up action isn't running already
        if (![randomSprite getActionByTag:kScaleUpActionTag])
        {
            // stop downscale action and run upscale action
            [randomSprite stopActionByTag:kScaleDownActionTag];
            CCAction *action = /* your scale up action */
            action.tag = kScaleUpActionTag;
            [randomSprite runAction:action];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was doing and the solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CCScaleBy if you want to scale to an absolute scale factor. Use CCScaleTo instead.

The problem with CCScaleBy is that if your scale is 1.5 and you scale down by 0.5 you end up with scale 1.0. But if for some reason the scale is interrupted and performed again when the node is scaled to 1.2 you end up doing a scale from 1.2 to 0.7.

Finally, if you want to be sure that a specific scale factor is used after scaling is done, create a CCSequence with a CCCallFunc or CCCallBlock at its end and setting the scale factor manually and forcibly to a specific value.